# Examples of Manifolds such that $\chi (X)=-3$

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, examples-counterexamples

I am trying to come up with an example of a closed oriented manifold with euler characteristic equal to $-3$. I have tried to use $\chi (\underbrace{T^2\mathbin{\#}\cdots \mathbin{\#} T^2}_{\text{$g$ times}})=2-2g$ and to come up with a free action of $Z_2$ there to take away the $2$ but without reaching anywhere. A hint would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try higher dimensions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some points.

1) An oriented manifold $M$ which occurs as the boundary of an oriented manifold $W$ necessarily has $\chi(M)$ even. This means that not only are all of your surfaces not going to work, but neither is anything that's the boundary of a manifold.

2) Every odd-dimensional manifold has $\chi(M) = 0$ (even non-oriented ones). So you can't try that.

3) $\chi(M \# N) = \chi(M) + \chi(N) - 1 - (-1)^n$ where $n$ is the dimension of $M$ and $N$. (Since we'd better be working with even-dimensional manifolds, this just says $\chi(M \# N) = \chi(M) + \chi(N) - 2$.) This says, then, if you can find a single manifold with euler characteristic 1, you can find one with Euler characteristic -3, either by connect-summing it with itself four times or by connect-summing something of euler characteristic zero twice.

So you just need to find a nice manifold with Euler characteristic 1. (Actually, any positive odd number will do.) The first place you can *possibly* do this is in dimension 4. Do you know any nice manifolds there?

Answer (score 9):

By the classification of surfaces, every closed oriented surface is a connected sum of tori, so you won't be able to find a $2$-dimensional example.  By Poincare duality, any closed odd-dimensional manifold has Euler characteristic $0$, so the smallest dimension where you can find an example is $4$.

To find a $4$-dimensional example, you can start with $\mathbb{C}P^2$, which has Euler characteristic $3$.  Can you see a way you can modify a closed oriented $4$-manifold to decrease its Euler characteristic by $2$?  Then you just have to repeat this three times to get a $4$-manifold of Euler characteristic $-3$.

Comment: Oops. We wrote more or less the exact same answer.