# Is there a non-trivial connected compact orientable topological manifold of Euler characteristic 1?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Is there a non-trivial connex compact orientable [topological manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold) of [Euler characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Topological_definition) $\chi = 1$?

*Remark*: the point has $\chi = 1$, but it is trivial. The [real projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane) has $\chi = 1$, but it is not orientable. The [wedge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum) of a sphere and a torus has  $\chi = 1$, but it is not a topological manifold. I don't know if the connexity is necessary.

Comment: You mean without boundary?

Comment: @Anubhav.K: A topological manifold has no boundary.

Comment: This is a near-duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764807/examples-of-manifolds-such-that-chi-x-3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\Bbb CP^2$ has Euler characteristic $3$. Now try to use that $\chi(M \# N) = \chi(M) + \chi(N) - 2$ for even-dimensional manifolds to construct a manifold with $\chi=1$.

Comment: argh, just wrote mine:) anyway, clearly nice answer!

Comment: $M \# N$ is the [connected sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum).

Answer (score 5):

$\mathbb{C}P^2\sharp S^1\times S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1 $